# What is the name of this linkage part?

Tags: tie-rod, connecting-rod

Car is a honda civic vti 1999 manual.

What is the name of this part?  I'm pretty sure its called the anti roll bar\sway\stabiliser bar LINKAGE, however if I remember right mechanic kept saying your 'tie rod link' 'tie rod something...' is loose and broken.  As you can see in one of the pics the part is completely broken off.

I notice in the comments somebody describes that it looks like a tie rod.  Are the components of the sway bar linkage known as tie rod or something.  I originally though he was telling me the tie rods needed changing and were making a knocking sound however when I searched repair videos it was clear its the damaged parts in question are not a tie rod  However I'm wondering why he kept describing these parts with the words tie rod.

[image: pic fro behind inside of front right wheel]

[image: pic from behind rear left wheel]

[image: pic from behind rear right wheel]

Comment: What year/make/model/engine/transmission? What part of the car are we looking at? Engine/transmission/rear differential/ front differential/suspension? It is a linkage with a bushing/tie rod type thing at either end, but you've not really given us anything to go on.

Comment: Be useful to know what the mechanic said exactly... Anti-roll bar? Tie rod? And a better picture would help with some more light.

Comment: @SolarMike I can't remember so am asking here.  I think he used both terms but definitely heard him say tie rod multiple times.  I think this is a anti roll bar linkage, however if so why did he keep saying tie rod?  Are the parts of the linkage called tie rods?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I have edited it, did add a description for the images but they don't seem to show in the question.

Comment: @JamesWilson - Those pictures are far superior to the original one ... TY for posting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solar Mike is correct.
The known terminology to anyone with shop experience will call it a "sway bar end link"
it provides stability and attempts to keep your tires planted to the pavement (which is where you want them planted, not in the air).

The most common name is "sway bar end link"
if you are looking to replace them, be sure to get new hardware (nuts) along with the actual part. 
there will be times and i have a feeling that this might be one of the just by looking at the pictures provided that rust will be your contender in this endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

It is an Anti-roll bar drop link, known for breaking or being the source of rattles and clonks.

Comment: Any idea why he kept referring to it as tie rod, paulster also said it 'has a tie rod type thing at the end' I thought tie rod was a completely different thing.

Comment: I lost one once on the LA freeways while pulling a camper; amazing how much a car rocks and rolls without them.